[MIPS]: branch delay slot is only on Pipeline implementation?
When I was trying to better understand how the jal instruction works, this question came to me.
From what I understand, "Branch delay slot" exists only in MIPS pipeline processor implementations, so the register $ra=PC+8.
But in single-cycle and multi-cycle implementations, there is no concept of "Branch delay slot", so in these implementations $ra=PC+4.
Is correct ?

Branch delay slot is an architectural / instruction set architecture concept, not an implementation concept.  A processor implementation must follow the architecture it reports to follow, there are no excuses that well, this benefits this implementation (so we'll do delay slots), or, this is hard for this other implementation (so we won't do delay slots).  That being said however, some MIPS instruction sets no longer honor the branch delay slot, and this means that software machine code for one will not run on the other and vice versa.
